# Como detectar se um elemento está sob outro elemento? (HTML, via javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, posicionamento

Gostaria de saber como detectar, de uma forma simples e que retorne as informações que preciso, se um elemento está sob o outro.
Já tentei pelo `offset`, mas foi bem difícil e não resultou em quase nada,pois havia muitos erros...

Por exemplo:

```css
p{background:red}
.teste{margin-left: -20px}
button{position: relative; top:-35px}
```

```html
<p>Elemento 0</p>
<button>Elemento 1</button><button class="teste">Elemento 2</button>
```

Perceba que o "elemento 2" está sobre o "elemento 1", e ambos estão sobre o "elemento 0".

Queria uma função em que nela eu mande o *elemento 2* e ela retorne os *elementos 1 e 0*, isto é, elementos que estão graficamente abaixo de *elemento 1*.

Comment: Se puder revisar a sua pergunta, está confusa neste trecho: "_Queria uma função em que eu mande o elemento 2 e ela retorne os elementos 1 e 0,..._" .. vc quer _mandar_ o elemento 2 pra onde?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), ele basicamente te retorna tanto a posição do elemento quanto o seu tamanho. Com essa informação só fazer a checagem dos outros elementos.

Uma forma de fazer essa checagem para descobrir os elementos abaixo é iterar sobre todos os elementos do DOM, veja como ficaria:

```js
function getBelowElements(el) {
    const sourceBounding = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    let belowElements = [];

    for (const currentElement of document.all) {
        const targetBounding = currentElement.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Se todas as condições forem falsas, é porque está tendo uma sobreposição
        if (!(sourceBounding.right < targetBounding.left ||
            sourceBounding.left > targetBounding.right ||
            sourceBounding.bottom < targetBounding.top ||
            sourceBounding.top > targetBounding.bottom)) {
            belowElements = [...belowElements, currentElement]; // Adiciona o elemento atual ao array de elementos sobrepostos
        }
    }

    return belowElements; // Retorna o array de elementos sobrepostos
}

console.log(getBelowElements(document.getElementsByClassName("teste")[0]));
```

```css
p{background:red}
.teste{margin-left: -20px}
button{position: relative; top:-35px}
```

```html
<p>Elemento 0</p>
<button>Elemento 1</button><button class="teste">Elemento 2</button>
<button>Elemento 3</button>
```

Isso é um pouquinho custoso dependendo da quantidade de elementos na sua página, mas não consegui pensar em uma forma mais simples.

Comment: Tem como limitar essa busca de elementos? Por exemplo:

getBelowElements(a, b)

::: Onde a é o elemento onde estou procurando e o b é o elemento que quero verificar se está sobrepondo algo.

Para não precisar procurar no documento inteiro...

Comment: @GleisonElias Seu comentário não está muito claro. Recomendo que você faça uma edição e coloque exatamente o que você precisa na sua pergunta, isso evita que ocorra respostas que não é exatamente o que você precisa.